# Multiprocessing always crashes out of memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Im using multiprocessing Process and Queue modules to process a huge amount of data. The issue is that the job is never done since it runs out of memory way before its finished.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

# Create Queues
inQueue  = Queue()
outQueue = Queue()        

# Create worker processes
ps = [Process(target=worker, args=(inQueue, outQueue)) for _ in range(cores)]

# Start worker processes
for p in ps: p.start()

# Fill the queue
for j in range(2000):
  spectrum = *1 by 4000 array*
  if spectrum.any():
    noise = *1 by 4000 array*
    inQueue.put( ( *lots of agrs* ) )

# results
ppxf_res = [outQueue.get() for _ in range(2000)]

# send stop signal to stop iteration
for _ in range(cores): inQueue.put('STOP')

# stop processes
for p in ps: p.join()
```

After this the results are stored in a pkl file. No matter how many cores I divide the workload into, it always crashes out of memory. Is there a way I could prevent this from happening?

!! UPDATE !!
So this would be the solution? Or do I need to do something else to clean the outQueue?

```
specBIN = * j by 4000 array which will be processed one by one by the worker *
# Create Queues
MAX_TASKS_IN_QUEUE = 100
inQueue  = Queue(MAX_TASKS_IN_QUEUE)
outQueue = Queue(MAX_TASKS_IN_QUEUE)      

# Create worker processes
ps = [Process(target=worker, args=(inQueue, outQueue)) for _ in range(cores)]

jstart = 0 
for n in range(MAX_TASKS_IN_QUEUE):
  
  jfin = int(jstart + 2000/MAX_TASKS_IN_QUEUE)
  # Start worker processes
  for p in ps: p.start()

  # Fill the queue
  for j in range(jstart,jfin):
    spectrum = np.array(specBIN[j])
    if spectrum.any():
      inQueue.put( ( *lots of agrs* ) )

  # results
  ppxf_res = [outQueue.get() for _ in range(nbins)]

  # send stop signal to stop iteration
  for _ in range(cores): inQueue.put('STOP')

  # stop processes
  for p in ps: p.join()
  
  with open('file_%s.pkl'%n,'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(ppxf_res, f)
    
  jstart = jfin
```

!! UPDATE !!

After saving the results within the function called by the worker it still crashes out of memory:

```
  # Create Queues
  inQueue  = Queue()
  outQueue = Queue()        

  # Create worker processes
  ps = [Process(target=workerPPXF, args=(inQueue, outQueue)) for _ in range(cores)]

  # Start worker processes
  for p in ps: p.start()

  # Fill the queue
  for j in range(nbins):
    spectrum = np.array(specBIN[j])
    if spectrum.any():
      noise = errBIN[j]
      inQueue.put( ( j, stp, mc, stars_templates, spectrum, noise, velscale, startST, goodpixels0, lam_gal, st_lib, stars_gas_templates, start, moments, component, gas_component, gas_names, MUSE_3D ) )
  
  # results
  #ppxf_res = [outQueue.get() for _ in range(nbins)]

  # send stop signal to stop iteration
  for _ in range(cores): inQueue.put('STOP')

  # stop processes
  for p in ps: p.join()

def workerPPXF(inQueue, outQueue):
    """
    Defines the worker process of the parallelisation with multiprocessing.Queue
    and multiprocessing.Process. 
    """
    for j, stp, mc, stars_templates, spectrum, noise, velscale, startST, goodpixels0, lam_gal, st_lib, stars_gas_templates, start, moments, component, gas_component, gas_names, MUSE_3D in iter(inQueue.get, 'STOP'):

      sol = run_ppxf(j, stp, mc, stars_templates, spectrum, noise, velscale, startST, goodpixels0, lam_gal, st_lib, stars_gas_templates, start, moments, component, gas_component, gas_names, MUSE_3D)

      with open('ppxf_res_%04d.pkl'%j,'wb') as out:
        pickle.dump(sol, out)
   
      #outQueue.put(( j, sol ))
```

As for the errors:

> (...) Process Process-117: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 314, in _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/gpfs/data/fs71474/iris/GALYKOS/MUSE/NGC4030_ius_100manypkl/pPXF_par_manypkl.py",
> line 205, in workerPPXF
> for j, stp, mc, stars_templates, spectrum, noise, velscale, startST, goodpixels0, lam_gal, st_lib, stars_gas_templates, start,
> moments, component, gas_component, gas_names, MUSE_3D in
> iter(inQueue.get, 'STOP'):   File
> "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py",
> line 122, in get
> return _ForkingPickler.loads(res) EOFError: Ran out of input Process Process-78: Process Process-29: Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 314, in _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/gpfs/data/fs71474/iris/GALYKOS/MUSE/NGC4030_ius_100manypkl/pPXF_par_manypkl.py",
> line 205, in workerPPXF
> for j, stp, mc, stars_templates, spectrum, noise, velscale, startST, goodpixels0, lam_gal, st_lib, stars_gas_templates, start,
> moments, component, gas_component, gas_names, MUSE_3D in
> iter(inQueue.get, 'STOP'):   File
> "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py",
> line 122, in get
> return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
> _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xfa'. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 314, in _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/gpfs/data/fs71474/iris/GALYKOS/MUSE/NGC4030_ius_100manypkl/pPXF_par_manypkl.py",
> line 205, in workerPPXF
> for j, stp, mc, stars_templates, spectrum, noise, velscale, startST, goodpixels0, lam_gal, st_lib, stars_gas_templates, start,
> moments, component, gas_component, gas_names, MUSE_3D in
> iter(inQueue.get, 'STOP'):   File
> "/home/fs71474/iris/usr/local/lib/Python-3.10.6/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py",
> line 122, in get
> return _ForkingPickler.loads(res) EOFError: Ran out of input (....)

!! UPDATE !!

I've changed the code to something that is not as abstract to me and it still crashes. Now I think the error clearly refers to lack of memory:

```
  jstart = 0 ; processes = []
  for c in range(cores):
    jfin = int(jstart + nbins/cores)
    p = Process(target=workerPPXF, args = (c, args, jstart, jfin))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
    jstart = jfin
  for p in processes:
    p.join()  

def workerPPXF(c, args, jstart, jfin):
  
  ppSol = []
  if jfin > nbins: jfin = nbins
  for j in range(jstart,jfin):
    spectrum = np.array(specBIN[j])
    if spectrum.any():
      noise = errBIN[j]
      sol = run_ppxf(j, args)
      ppSol.append(sol)
          
  with open('ppxf_res_%03d.pkl'%c,'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(ppSol, f)
```

Error:

> slurmstepd: error: Detected 86 oom-kill event(s) in
> StepId=322772.batch. Some of your processes may have been killed by
> the cgroup out-of-memory handler.

So Slurm kills my processes because it lacks memory. The question is, how does the processing of 2000 objects (not 2 million...) depletes the memory of a cluster with 500Gb RAM?! What am I doing wrong that can be optimized not to consume so much memory? Is it python saving every single computation it does in all cores? Its supposed to be straightforward.. for each of the 2000 objects simply compute it, save the output, and go to the next one without accumulating anything on RAM.. Why does it does that and how can I prevent it from increasing RAM usage at every computation?!

Comment: It's not clear how the output from the first piece of code is used in the second because you have not provided code for `wrapper` nor have you supplied a stack trace. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i can give you the wrapper but you wont understand it because its just calling the function that will be parallelized

Comment: Then you need to provide that function also. Do you understand what is meant by minimal and reproducible? If we don't see the code you are running how are we supposed to know where the memory issue is?

Comment: well, that function is huge, calling several other functions. its spread between multiple files

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to limit the amount of work fed into the workers until you get rid of the results.

```py
MAX_TASKS_IN_QUEUE = 40
inQueue  = Queue(MAX_TASKS_IN_QUEUE)
outQueue = Queue(MAX_TASKS_IN_QUEUE)
```

doing this will block anyone who tries to put more items in the queue when there are 40 items in the queue, essentially limiting the memory usage, but items must be taken out of the queue in order to keep the application running, so you must launch other processes to read from `outQueue` and save the files to disk **Before** you start putting work into the `inQueue`.

Comment: do you mean something like what ill add now to my original question?

Comment: sorry, there was an error. ill post it after i correct it for you to tell me if this would solve the issue. thanks!

Comment: @faeriewhisper i think the best option for you is to just process them in small batches to not run out of memory, because even if you could get your current code working the way you are currently doing it, the error handling for it is quite involved, and you will run into a lot of deadlocks.

Comment: but the second example i provided (that now i removed otherwise it would be too confusing) was dividing the work these 2000 things i must process into smaller parts and saving the results in different pkl files that were being combined after. the problem is that it still crashes out of memory no matter in how many cores i divide the job... i think because it still has to save the results of the ones already processed in a list so that in the end it saves them.

Comment: what if i save the results in a file inside the function that is called multiple times by the worker so that i wont even need the output from outQueue? would this solve the problem?

Comment: @faeriewhisper yes it would.

Comment: no, it didnt solve the problem.. it still runs out of memory...

Comment: Process Process-117:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ....multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File ".../multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "...._manypkl.py", line 205, in workerPPXF
    for .... in iter(inQueue.get, 'STOP'):
  File "....multiprocessing/queues.py", line 122, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: @faeriewhisper `ran out of input` is not running out of **memory** .... don't send anything except numbers and numpy arrays and strings on that queue, or lists and dictionaries of them.

Comment: congratulations, you have just wasted a few days of your life chasing an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) because you didn't post the original error here and assumed it was an out of memory problem.

Comment: then what is it?, how can i solve it? sorry to be wasting your time too...

Comment: so, lets recap.. i have a data-cube that i want to process. this data-cube is made of 2000 arrays (spectra). each of these 2000 arrays will be placed in queue to be processed. in the beginning everything goes perfectly fine, the arrays are processed very fast without problem. after some hours the arrays are processed much slower. after some more hours they are processed so slower its virtually not doing anything. after some more hours all cores crashed.

Comment: i though this would be a memory problem because also the top command shows that the more time it passes the more memory it uses, and it can be a very significant percentage. also, it kind of looks like it since in the beginning there is no problem and the more time it passes the slower everything becomes. also, if i process this same data-cube without parallelizing i dont seem to find any problem (i didnt let it finish because it would take a week but after a couple of days it was running without issues)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Now we will be using a multiprocessing pool that provides the ability to submit tasks in "chunks" so that you do not have to do the chunking you have been doing. Function `compute_chunksize` computes an efficient value if memory were no obstacle. So you may have to avoid this function and specify a hard-coded, smaller value than the one that would be computed. The output is now one file containing all the return values from `run_ppxf` back to back instead of `cores` files each containing a list of these values. This should reduce memory requirements further since the values are being output one by one as soon as they are returned from `workerPPXF`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from functools import partial
import pickle

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def workerPPXF(args, index):
    spectrum = np.array(specBIN[index])
    if spectrum.any():
        noise = errBIN[index]
        sol = run_ppxf(index, args)
        return sol
    else:
        return None

def main():
    cores = cpu_count()
    pool = Pool(cores)
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(nbins, cores)
    print('Using chunksize', chunksize)

    with open('ppxf_res.pkl', 'wb') as f:
       worker = partial(workerPPXF, args)
       # May need to use a smaller chunksize value if we still have
       # memory issues:
       for sol in pool.imap(worker, range(nbins), chunksize=chunksize):
           if sol is not None:
               pickle.dump(f, sol)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you do not care what the order of results are returned and written out, then use the more efficient `imap_unordered` method instead of the 'imap` method.

Comment: many thanks for you help. just to see if i understood correctly then, the N_TASKS would be the total number of processes i put in queue right, so the total number of things i must process..?

Comment: now im not even doing anything with the results (i the function called by the worker im saving a file in the hard disk for each process) and it still crashes

Comment: N_TASKS is the number of *items* (not *processes*) you are putting to `inq`. This is so `process_outq` knows how many items it should be getting `outq` assuming a one-to-one correspondence. If there was not a one-to_one correspondence, then each `Process` (there are `N_PROCESSES` processes) should put to `outq` a *sentinel* value (`None`, perhaps) after it has retrieved a `None` item from the `inq`. Then `process_outq` terminates after getting `N_PROCESSES` of these sentinels.

Comment: The above code was working on the assumption that your memory problem arose from the task queue growing too large. It seems now, based on what you say, you have a memory-related issue in your actual worker function, which you have not posted. So I do not know what else to suggest other than looking at the stack trace (again, not posted) and seeing where you run out of memory and try to figure out why.

Comment: thanks again. so ill change my thread to add the error ok? relatively to the worker function its really quite complex and calls several functions in different files. but the thing is that if i run this function without parallelizing there is no memory problem, just takes too long..

Comment: First, a few observations: It appears you do not require an output queue and therefore there is no need to start a thread to read from it, so don't create one and pass it to your worker function. You also have not constructed your input queue with a *maxsize* argument as suggested. But no matter as it appears your problem is not a memory error (at least, not yet) but rather an error getting items from the input queue. Why did you say you have a memory error and why have I spent time addressing that if you do not have a memory error? (more...)

Comment: I don't know what all the objects you are putting on the input queue but it *appears* that the error occurs in de-serializing one of them.

Comment: I thought it was a memory error because it behaves like it (the first processes it computes them very fast but the more time it passes the slower is the process until it crashes completely). also i i do the top command i see the memory usage going to the rooftop.

Comment: im sorry, i dont know what is "de-serializing" (im a scientist, not a programmer). it is not a problem of processing the specific object. if it was the processing wouldnt be slower and slower the more the time passes. also, when i compute them without parallelization there is no problem

Comment: Did you try using the *maxsize* argument for the input queue? Re "de-serialization": When an object is put on a queue to be retrieved in a different process (and therefore a different address space), `pickle` is used to store out the contents of the object as a byte string (serialization) and when it is gotten from the queue, the object must be reconstituted from the byte string (de-serialization).

Comment: oh ok, got it. i didnt try the maxsize because i dont fully understand how it works. so basically im adding the processing of all my objects to queue and then i divide these processes by the number of cores that i want the data to be parallelized. by using the maxsize how am i sure that all the processes will be processed?

Comment: Nothing is sure. But by setting *maxsize* to `N`, your loop that executes `inQueue.put(,,,)` will block once it has put `N` items (tasks) on the queue. When a child process gets a task from the queue, there will be `N - 1` items on the queue and the main process will now unblock and be able to submit another task to the queue. But there will never be more than `N` items on the queue. This *should* limit the amount of memory being used by the queue. Try setting `N` to `N_PROCESSES to minimize memory yet each child process still has something to work on. **But your problem may *not* be memory.**

Comment: Ok so if i understand it will compute all objects but N at a time. Once these N are done it will continue to the next N. Ill try that. Also, I started some experiments, a) with only 200 objects to process, and b) all the objects to be processed only in one core, so in serial. Ill let you know how these go. Thank you so much for your help, im getting desperate with this...

Comment: so, i have some results.. the run with limit in N_PROCESSES is just too slow.. I dont know if 40 is a small value but in this way it will never finish. maybe there is a way to understand what is the optimal value..? the serial one also goes very slow (obviously). it didnt crash but its not secure that it wont later, when it has computed more objects. the one with 200 finished very fast without any problem. in addition ive change the code to use the Process package in a different way (ill update again the thread) and i have a new error after processing about 40% of the 2000 total objects.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421068/error-in-slurm-cluster-detected-1-oom-kill-events-how-to-improve-running-jo) relevant?

Comment: no, i dont think so :( so in the end all my tests failed... after ~600 objects processed it runs out of memory, no matter which python multiprocessing tool I try (besides the example given in the last update I also tried apply_async). I tried to limit the memory in SLURM, to limit the maximum number of processes, everything, nothing seems to work. I really think that python is saving everything coming out of the processes Im computing and eventually it becomes so big that it crashes. if so the question becomes how to prevent it from doing that... any idea?

Comment: Actually, I did miss something in your previous edit. You seem to have `nbins` items you need to compute in parallel. You have `cores` cores and so you seem to be computing `core` ranges and passing to your worker function these ranges. Each of your `cores` worker functions will be computing a `ppSol` list. So all instances of `ppSol` can add up to  having `nbins` values of whatever `run_ppfx` returns. That could be a lot of memory. Putting a *maxsize* value of `cores` on your queue accomplishes nothing since you are only submitting `cores` tasks. But this is submitting everything at once.

Comment: See `Update`, my last best shot.

Comment: I finally managed to solve it :D and it was by completely removing the multiprocessing package and use instead ray. I does the job very fast in 100 cores without complaining about memory. In all my tests I couldnt figure out why multiprocessing's need for RAM significantly increases with time and how to prevent this behavior. But no need since ray does the trick ;) Thank you so much for your time!